# How can I return an image to my 'index.html' file in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

As the title indicates, I'm trying to return an image to my index.html from my Flask API, an image list to be exact. The problem is that my current code doesn't seem to return the image to the index.html.
Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    images = [
        Image.open(r"./idel.png"),
        Image.open(r"./idel1.png")
    ]

    animation = ImageSequence.all_frames(images)

    return render_template('index.html', animation=animation)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=2231)`
```

I tried using
`'return send_files('animation', mimetype='/')`
but it didn't work.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Usually with flask, you dont need to pass a list of images. You can easily pass the path of an image stored in the static folder and use it in your html. For reference, https://kanchanardj.medium.com/how-to-add-images-to-html-in-a-flask-app-4dbcc92e3aeb